# A (simple?) RegEx question for global non capturing groups

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have the string `Hello {{name}}, how are you doing today?` I'm trying to grab `name` from that string.

So far, I have `/\{{2}[a-z0-9]*\}{2}/gi`. The problem, is, it grabs `{{name}}` and not `name`. Without the global flag it works fine, but I'm trying to get every instance of words within double brackets, so it's not quite right... I'm no RegEx pro so I'm hoping someone can help me out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution would be to use lookaround assertions so the `{{` and `}}` don't get picked up, however JavaScript regex doesn't support lookbehind, it only supports lookahead.

So one alternative is to place your text in a capture group and grab what's inside:

```
/\{{2}([a-z0-9]*)\}{2}/gi
```

To get every capture, make a `RegExp` object with your regex, and iterate through the results of its `exec()` function. For example:

```
var str = 'Hello {{name}}, how are you doing {{date}}?';
var re = /\{{2}([a-z0-9]*)\}{2}/gi;
var words = [];
var match;

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    words.push(match[1]);
}
```

[jsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/j5SPV)

Or as Gumbo suggests in his comment, manually strip out the `{{` and `}}` from your array of matches.

Comment: It was surprising to me, but this doesn't work, as the OP said, because of the /g flag. It basically makes no difference. I guess it's because of how javascript handles regexes; in perl it'd work fine.

Comment: @crimson_penguin: You need to run `RegExp.exec()` iteratively to get all the captures.

Comment: @crimson_penguin: That’s no problem: `matches.map(function(val) { return val.substring(2, val.length-2); })`.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, but like @crimson_penguin was saying, it returns it regardless of the capture group... I figured I could strip the values later, but it'd be easier if they just were extracted that way rather than having to iterate over an array like @Gumbo recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Yea as mentioned, pattern matching on the 2 opening and closing braces is the way to go (assuming the name does not have curly braces in succession of the number of 2 within itself, either opening/closing)

> `/\{{2}([a-z0-9]+)*\}{2}/gi`